# Adding swipe gesture to listview like ViewPager which is below ViewPager.

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a LitView below ViewPager(See attached picture), content of listview changes on ViewPager swipe. I want to add swipe on ListView too, so that content of listview should be changed when listview receives a swipe gesture. How to achieve this?

Also I want to reduce the height of the Viewpager when user scrolls on listview, so that it wont occupy too much height.

Any leads would be helpful. Thanks![image]

Comment: Aren't there `Fragment`s in the `ViewPager`? Why not just create fragments with different `ListView`s? It is not good practice to have two views that scroll the same way in the same place, as the user will get confused about which view he/she is scrolling.

Comment: No.Not as of now. Reason being -:
1) I want to show 'partial' next page(Only current view pager content not listview content) in ViewPager.
2) There will be some lag(~500ms) between ViewPager swipe and Listview Swipe(Also Vice versa).